# Source Control Explorer - 0 is not a valid changeset number

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, source-control-explorer

When trying to get the latest version of a folder, I'm getting the error:

> 0 is not a valid changeset number. Please specify a number between 1 and 2147483647

I'm unsure what is causing this, but I am fairly confident that it isn't completely downloading the file because of this error.

I am right clicking on the folder and selecting "Get Latest Version".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, managed to fix it.

What I did was enter the file via Source Control Explorer and select "Get Latest Version" for each folder/file inside of the folder which is giving me that error. I haven't had any issues with it since.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Ok, done that. I was going to mark it straight away but I had to wait two days before I could do it due to Stack Overflow's rules.

Comment: turns out the reason was that somehow my shelvesets and changesets were getting mixed after i did undo on a shelveset to get the latest of changeset...so the files were still present even after i deleted the folder and tried to get the latest version from source control, doing what you said made me realize i have changes on a project i just did Get latest on..fixed those and it worked fine.